# How log in JSON format in .Net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It's my first time developing a .net core app. I'm currently following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging?tabs=aspnetcore2x) and using `ILogger` in my controller.

However I need my logs to be formated in JSON (because another process in my data center takes them and index them in that format).

What's the best way to accomplish this? I'm a little confused. Is this something that can be achieved by creating a provider?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an existing provider, you don't need to create one yourself.

I personally like Serilog:

- [Set up for .NET Core](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore)
- [JSON format configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#formatting-json)